# CSS Animation : Pause and change position

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am animating a div's left / top property to move it across the screen. (Prefixes removed for brevity)

```
animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;

@keyframes moveX {
  from { left: 0; } to { left: 100%; }
}

@keyframes moveY {
  from { top: 0; } to { top: 100%; }
}
```

Upon clicking on the div I add a CSS class which pauses the CSS animation, and should center the div in the screen. CSS:

```
  /* Pause Animation */
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused; 
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused; 
  -o-animation-play-state: paused; 
  animation-play-state: paused; 

  /* Position Center */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
```

The left / top value is not being applied.

How can I pause and keep an animations current state, change the position of the div, and then return to the animation.

Reduced test case here:
http://test.addedlovely.com/pmr/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the div you still have

```
-webkit-animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;
-o-animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;
animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}
```

set the attribute to: this should do the trick

```
-webkit-animation: none;
-moz-animation: none;
-o-animation: none;
animation: none;
}
```

Comment: Adding animation none lose the position of the div, so when the class is removed it jumps back to the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the animation's control of your `top`/`left` and `margin-top`/`margin-left` overrides any such values you might try to set for the click-listener. And if you remove the animation and re-add it, it resets to zero. So instead, you need a way to center your div that doesn't interact with the values you're animating.

To work around this, toggle from `absolute` or `fixed` positioning to `flex` positioning, and center via `justify-content` and `align-items`. Nest your divs as illustrated below for the centering to work properly. And set `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` so that the animation remembers its last position between pauses.

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/secag/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="div" class="animated running"</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

#parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.center-children {
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation: moveX 10s linear 0s infinite alternate both, moveY 7s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveX {
  from { left: 0; } to { left: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveY {
  from { top: 0; } to { top: 100%; }
}  

.paused {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

.running {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  var div = document.getElementById('div');

  div.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.classList.contains('paused')) {
      this.parentElement.classList.remove('center-children');
      this.classList.remove('paused');
      this.classList.add('running');
    } else {
      this.classList.remove('running');
      this.classList.add('paused');
      this.parentElement.classList.add('center-children');
    }
  });

});
```

DOCS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: Thanks, in part yes, that keeps the state of the animation, but doesn't resolve changing the position.

Comment: Could you have the click-listener add/remove a custom `centered` class? What other CSS and JS is in play?

Comment: @addedlovely, I'm curious how my suggestion above went for you…?